# can't get createResource to refetch when sourceSignal changes

Tags: solid-js

I might not understand fully how createResource is meant to work but from what I can tell, if you pass it a sourceSignal, it will get the initial data and then refetch data when the sourceSignal changes.

Below is what I have and it fetches initial data fine, but when startDate / endDate updates, nothing happens with createResource.

`getDates()` is a hook where I update the start and end date. I can confirm this works with a `createEffect(() => console.log(startDate());` as well as other parts of the UI that changes with the date updates.

```js
export const Screen = () => {
   const { startDate, endDate } = getDates();

   const getBookings = async ({ stDate, enDate }) => {
     const result = await client
       .query(bookingsQuery, {
         startDate: stDate().toISODate(),
         endDate: enDate().toISODate(),
       })
       .toPromise();
       return result.data;
   };

   const [bookings] = createResource(
     { stDate: startDate, enDate: endDate },
     getBookings
   );

      ...
  
      return (...)
}
```

I tried to pass the start/end date signals directly to the fetch function and have a createEffect do a refetch when signals updated but this did not work as expected.

```js
export const Screen = () => {
   const { startDate, endDate } = getDates();

   const getBookings = async () => {
     const result = await client
       .query(bookingsQuery, {
         startDate: startDate().toISODate(),
         endDate: endDate().toISODate(),
       })
       .toPromise();
       return result.data;
   };

   const [bookings, {refetch}] = createResource(etBookings);

   createEffect(() => {
    refetch();
   }, startDate)

      ...
  
      return (...)
}
```